# Suddenly can't connect to my home network (WiFi)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I've been using Ubuntu on my laptop for about 8 months, and have never had a problem connecting to my home wireless network. But all of a sudden, I am unable to connect. I can see the network, and the system still automatically tries to connect, but it just keeps trying (unsuccessfully) to connect. I have taken a look at similar questions, but have not been able to solve the problem.

Note: I can still connect to other WiFi networks (like at school)

Any support is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If any of the below answer is optimum for you, please accept. If, you have found different solution please mention. Else, continue (iterate till time you get the answer! ;) )

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same thing now. I can even connect to a tethered WiFi from my phone, but can't connect to my home WiFi (it just keeps trying to connect, but doesn't manage to).

Answer (score 1):

### Silly first steps

1. Have you tried restarting your home router? I know this might be a silly comment but sometimes is just the router. Disconnect from the wall and reconnect if necessary.
2. Verify that the password was not changed by a family member or friend. Might be as simple as that.
3. Delete the connection...

### Delete the connection

Go to the `network indicator` (indicators are the icon applets in the top right: volume, network, clock/calendar, etc...):

Enter into `Edit connections...`

Select your home network on the list and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Try to connect again entering the information as needed.

### Still not working?

Let me know and will try to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Though I have already tried the above :(

Comment: Any idea when the problem began? A month, two, a week? We could try to run on an earlier kernel version to check. You should also try to add hardware information. Run: `sudo lshw -C network`. Add the output to your question.

Comment: One of the silly first steps (namely, number 3, deleting the connection) worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

1st suggestion

Verify that password. Every one makes mistakes... fortunately, passwords have zero tolerance for mistakes :) Also, make sure the security type is correctly set (WPA, WPA2, WEP, etc.)

2nd suggestion

If you own other devices that ARE able to connect, check their gateway, subnet, IP, DNS information and try manually setting your laptop with the same information but w/a different IP. Verify there are no other devices on your network fighting over the same IP address. (If you don't own any other devices, hard wire your laptop with an ethernet cord and note the same information then manually set the WIFI connection)

3rd suggestion

You may have possibly installed another kernel during an update/upgrade that broke your wireless. First open up a terminal and type:

```
uname -r
```

Write down the output on paper or other device. Next, type:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

If you see more than one kernel installed: reboot your computer, but keep pressing Shift as your computer is starting so you can get to your GRUB menu. From there, use the arrow buttons to select a different kernel (than the one you wrote down) to boot from and see if anything changes.

BTW

Do you administer your router?

Also,

Have you tried booting from a live cd/usb & trying to establish a WIFI connection?

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved by changing the channel on my WiFi router (in my case from channel 3 to 9). Funnily enough, after switching back to channel 3 again, Ubuntu could connect to the same WiFi on the old channel again. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I got the solution from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1177749/119592

Answer (score -1):

For new readers:
sometimes we ignore possible problems around ourselves(E.g. wrong password):
make sure **Access Control** option is disable or modified on your router. or you can solve this problem by changing WiFi channel as mentioned before.