# Particular WiFi network not detected

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, broadcom

I installed yesterday Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot on a computer usually used with Windows 7.

Everything went fine, except that I am unable to connect to my WiFi network. The weirdest thing being that my Network card seems to work perfectly: Ubuntu's Network Manager detects all the surrounding WiFi networks, except for mine, which is called "WiFi-2.4-68B7".

I already tried different solutions, none worked:

1. I configured "WiFi-2.4-68B7" in the "known networks" and tried to access it through the "Connect to hidden network tool".
2. I checked whether Ubuntu was detecting my Network chipset correctly, which appears to be the case:

> dd@dd:~$ sudo lspci
>
> Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

3. I tried reinstalling the Broadcom driver for my BCM4313

> dd@dd:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source

4. I also tried the solution proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819615/d-link-2750u-wi-fi-router-not-showing-in-ubuntu), but with no result.

I am out of ideas to solve the problem. It should be noted I can connect just fine to my WiFi network when I boot from Windows 7, the problem is thus not from the hardware.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you!

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` (in a terminal window) will show you interesting log messages.

Comment: Can you set to router to channel 1, 6, or 11?

Comment: If your AP is on a channel higher than 11, it won't be seen

Comment: Thank you Jeremy31! I discovered that my Internet provider had set my WiFi network to channel 13, probably because I encountered connectivity issues. I struggled a bit, but I managed to switch it to channel 3, and the network is now visible. That was the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks much. This comment of yours "If your AP is on a channel higher than 11, it won't be seen" really helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy31, it appeared that the problem came from the fact that my WiFi network was set to channel 13. After switching it back to a channel <11, I can now see the network and connect to it without problem.

Answer (score 2):

Changing Channel fixed my problem. To see which channel is good for you, run this command on ubuntu.

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Frequency | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

if you encounter an error say, wlan0 doesn't support scanning then, run this command

`ifconfig`

make sure you have installed net-tools if **you can't run ifconfig**

`sudo apt install net-tools`

look for output -  two words **wl** mine was **wlp2s0**, so the command would be

`sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan | grep Frequency | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

The “sort -n” command will rank the **channels in order of fastest to slowest**

In the router, you change your channel.

then restart your network-manager

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Alternatively, you **can also check if wifi is blocked** -
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309753/330133

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me too, although in my case, I could connect to the same network perfectly fine before an update on the channel that now didn't work, so it must be something that the update messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its an issue over the type of Network? Are you connecting to a 5gHz or a 2.4gHz network? I know that I sometimes have issues with the 5gHz networks being picked up.  I had to you Wine to set up my drivers.  It sounds like you are technically more adept than I am so I won't bother giving you instructions on how I did that...unless you arent sure how to use wine. Then I would be happy to help/   Also check to see that windows is disconection from your network so the router knows to allow you to connect. You wouldnt be using static IP would you? if so that could be the case...

Comment: I don't remember the BCM4313 being capable of 5 GHz